# Installing IIS on Windows 7

Tags: iis

I have installed IIS on my PC according to the guidelines in this link http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/  but when I type http://localhost in my browser it displays nothing. What is the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

They should make it clearer that

**IF you are using Starter or Home Basic editions, the result you get is expected.**